# R DBI / RPostgreSQL-- connection succeeds but dbListTables returns no tables

Tags: r

The following code connects to my PostgreSQL database successfully (or appears to, at any rate), but attempt to issue queries were met with "relation does not exist" errors, so I tried dbListTables, which doesn't return any tables at all.  The database name passed to dbConnect is correct, and the tables do exist.  I think the code I'm using is exactly the same as what I was using recently, which worked successfully.  Any ideas?

```
> library(RPostgreSQL)
Loading required package: DBI
> drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
> con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="mydb", user="user", password=password)
> dbListTables(con)
character(0)
```

I'm new to both R and DBI, so I'm sure I could be missing something extremely simple...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: More info-- I tried issuing a dbConnect command without specifying the username and password, expecting that if it was actually trying to connect to the correct database, it should fail (my local user name, with PostgreSQL uses if one is not specified, does not have an account in the specified database).  It failed as expected, which seems to indicate that it is trying to connect to the proper database (or at least the proper database server-- my local username does not have an account in any of the database, such as template1, that exist on the server instance).  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved-- I was right; it was something incredibly simple (and very, very stupid) on my part.  I was running the script from the wrong server.  The server I was running it from has an empty copy of the database I was attempting to connect to, so everything succeeded, and the empty result from dbListTables was correct.  Once I switched servers (or simply specified the host on the other server), everything worked.

Comment: And it as an edit to your question, or a comment.  This is no answer in the spirit of the site.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.Connet to MySQL

a)if Mysql is installed in your system, if not install it.

b)download the RMySQL IN R

`library(RMySQL)`

`drv = dbDriver("MySQL 5.0.1")`

make sure MySQL version is correct.

`con = dbConnect(drv,host="localhost",dbname="test",user="root",pass="root")`

use local host or use the server i.e ip address

use the required database name, user name and password

`album = dbGetQuery(con,statement="select * from table")`

run required query

`close(con)`

## 2.Another way to connect database

a)first install any database like MySQL,Oracle,SQL Server

b)install the ODBC connector for database

`library(Rodbc)`

`channel <- odbcConnect("test", uid="ripley", pwd="secret")`

test is the connection name of odbc conector which user has to set manualy

user can find this in Administrator tool

`res <- sqlFetch(ch, "table name")`

A table can be retrieved as a data frame

`res<-sqlQuery(channel, paste("select query"))`

part of the with condition one table can be retrieved as a data frame

`sqlSave(channel, dataframe)`

to save a dataframe to the database(dont use "res<-" something like this)

like user can use

`sqlCopy()`
`sqlDrop()`

`sqlTables()`

`close(channel)`

always close the connection

Comment: Wrong backend.  The question was about RPostgreSQL